# kendo ui DropDownList pre select first element

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui dropdownlist

```
<select id="mySelect" 
        kendo-drop-down-list 
        k-options="controller.mySelect"
        ng-model="controller.model">
</select>
```

Then when I change another select I am successfully refreshing the select by

```
 $("#initiative_select").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
```

But the initial selection is blank, I want to make the first item selected, 
I have try to do that on dataBound by

```
dataBound: function(e) {
     e.sender.select(e.sender.dataItem(0));
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 7):

I think you could use this on your **dataBound** function

```
if (this.select() === -1) { //check whether any item is selected
   this.select(0);
   this.trigger("change");
}
```

As mentioned by ggkrustev, the [issue on github](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/312)

[a DEMO here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eYUTA)